# rake sometimes won't work until "rvm use"

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm

I've got Ruby, Rails, Rake and friends all working pretty well using RVM on OSX, but when I start a new shell (new tab in Terminal.app) rake tasks seem to "lose" their environment:

```
$ rake my_module:my_task
Could not find uglifier-1.2.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I issue "rvm use" (which, I believe merely prints the current ruby, but does not alter anything) then it works fine:

```
$ rvm use
Using /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
$ rake my_module:my_task   # works fine now!
```

It seems to happen when a new shell is started. I have rvm installed as a single-user installation, with the following at the bottom of my .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I've verified that my .bash_profile is in fact executing by putting some echo statements after that line; I see the echo on the command line when I open a new tab, so it seems to be working. Any idea why rake doesn't work without "rvm use"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting rvm ruby to default ruby

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194 --default
```

This should use the rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194 every time as default.